# Outlook items suddenly disapears from inbox after synchronization

Tags: exchange, outlook

We had some disk problems on Exchange server. We had to fix the Exchange 2007 using eseutil. Everything works fine with the exception of the following problem with one e-mail account.

All inbox messages of mentioned e-mail account are fully accessible through the OWA.
When any user creates new Outlook profile (using .OST mode) and starts synchronizing, all inbox messages are visible in the Outlook's inbox folder untill the Inbox synchronizing is completed. Once the synchronizing progress bar reaches 100% (and the Outlook starts synchronizing Sent items or another folder), most of messages disappears from the inbox view of the Outlook. The .OST file size does not reduce.

New mails (delivered after Exchange server crash) remains all in the inbox.

There is no special view or filter applied in the Outlook.
The problem has been reproduced on two different computers (Vista+Office2007, Win7+Office2010).

We assume there is some problem on the Exchange server but we don't know how to fix it. 
Can anybody give us some advice?